# is adobe acrobat sdk library useful to render pdf's in custom application?

Tags: sdk, acrobat, adobe-pdf-library

I would like to ask if the acrobat sdk allows me to create an application that is able to render a pdf document from inside my application, that is, without the user having to open the adobe application along, but just having to have it installed on the system. thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, the Acrobat SDK is for use with Acrobat, as its name implies.  What you need is the Adobe PDF Library (APDFL), which is sold and supported by [Datalogics](http://datalogics.com/products/pdfl/).  There are also a number of other third party PDF SDKs, some of which are quite good and almost all are far less expensive.  If you haven't already made a decision, I highly recommend you investigate them.

Comment: From [What is the Acrobat Software Developer Kit? | Adobe Developer Connection](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/overview.html):
"You can also use IAC support to render a PDF file into an external application window instead of the Acrobat window."

Comment: @KennyEvitt I guess you didn't read the entire article. Pay attention to this quote: "Besides the technologies provided by the Acrobat SDK, you can also use the PDF Library (PDFL) to develop applications that create and manipulate PDF documents but do not interact with Acrobat. For more information, see Adobe PDF Library."

Comment: Bottom line: If you want to manipulate PDF files without installing Acrobat first, then you need the Adobe PDF Library. The Acrobat SDK will not suffice.

Comment: I guess you didn't read *the question*. You're correct that the APDFL *can also be used to render PDFs*, but the original question doesn't ask how to manipulate PDF files *without* installing Acrobat first. It explicitly asks if the *Acrobat* SDK is useful for rendering PDFs! And it is! And it explicitly mentions "having to have it [Acrobat] installed on the system". And the SDK is free, unlike the APDFL.

Comment: @KennyEvitt Sheesh. I disagree but this argument is pointless.

Comment: Why is this argument pointless? You assert that the Acrobat SDK isn't useful for rendering PDFs yet Adobe's documentation says that it can be used to do exactly that. Is there some other reason why it's not useful even tho it's possible? The original question seems to consider having Acrobat installed to be a non-issue; why do you think that's wrong? The alternative you provide is expensive and seemingly overkill for simply rendering a PDF. Why not include whatever info I'm missing in your answer?

Comment: @KennyEvitt It's pointless because your complaint is pedantic. I made it quite clear there are other options that are much less expensive. Answering it yourself is a better option than berating me.

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes

From [What is the Acrobat Software Developer Kit? | Adobe Developer Connection](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/overview.html):

> You can also use IAC support to render a PDF file into an external application window instead of the Acrobat window.

So, you can render a PDF using the Acrobat SDK in a custom application without the user needing to open Acrobat but it does need to be installed on the system running the custom application.

#### Alternatives

The Adobe PDF Library is an alternative means of rendering PDFs in a custom application and with it you could do so *without* needing to install Acrobat on the computer running the custom application. But it's expensive, e.g. thousands of dollars (per year?). [And it's print output doesn't exactly match Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/library.html) [emphasis mine]:

> Improved print output **to bring it closer to Acrobat**

There are also many many other PDF libraries with which you could render a PDF in a custom application.